# Rails Deleted User model and i get uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, command-line, terminal

I accidentally created a "Uset" model in rails instead of "User". Right after, I created another "User" model. To delete it, I entered

```
rails destroy model Uset
```

And after that I did

```
rake db:migrate
```

My rake was aborted and I got an error saying

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Uset
```

I kept trying to delete Uset and User but nothing worked even after I did

```
bundle exec rake db:rollback
```

It's not even letting me run the rails server.

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: There is a Uset constant on the project, it could be in your tests folder or some other folder. I recommend you to search "Uset" in all your project and remove the files and/or lines containing this word

Comment: You have to run `rake db:rollback` before you delete your migration file. But in your case I would recommend you to run `rake db:migrate:status` and try to find the version of the deleted migration and then run `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Also, this [link](https://makandracards.com/makandra/40171-how-to-fix-rake-db-rollback-does-not-work) might help you!